# Undefined index Php Error post method

Tags: php

My HTML From Code :

```
<form action="#" class="Test" method="post">
<label>Please Choose Your Place :</label>
 <input type="text" required list="Places" autocomplete="on"/>
 <datalist id="Places">
 <option value="EG"></option>
 <option value="USA"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
</datalist>
 <label>Where are you go? :</label>
 <input type="text" required list="Place" autocomplete="on"/>
 <datalist id="Place">
 <option value="EG"></option>
 <option value="USA"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
</datalist>
 <input name="OK" type="submit"/>
```

my php code :

```
    if(isset($_POST['OK']))
    {
        $Places=$_POST['Places'];
        $Place=$_POST['Place'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM 'test' WHERE Places='$Places' and Place='$Place' and describt='$describt'";
        $query=mysql_query($sql);

    while (mysql_fetch_row($query))
    {
```

> Notice: Undefined index: Places in G:\Xampp\htdocs\S\index.php on line 41
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Place in G:\Xampp\htdocs\S\index.php on line 42
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: describt in G:\Xampp\htdocs\S\index.php on line 43
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in G:\Xampp\htdocs\S\index.php on line 46

Please help me

Comment: probably not matching the key with `name` attribute of html `input` tag. post your html code

Comment: Rewrite code for you?? SO is not a writing service.

Comment: Post the html form you are using to see the input tags.

Comment: @IronyStack I did it

Comment: check my answer replace `id` with `name`

Comment: @MoatazMuhammed - You need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve your question and learn why you are receiving downvotes.

Comment: @IronyStack i'll try thank you very much about your help

Comment: @MilanChheda i'll see, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use name attribute not id

```
<form action="#" class="Test" method="post">
<label>Please Choose Your Place :</label>
 <input type="text" required list="Places" autocomplete="on"/>
 <datalist name="Places">
 <option value="EG"></option>
 <option value="USA"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
</datalist>
 <label>Where are you go? :</label>
 <input type="text" required list="Place" autocomplete="on"/>
 <datalist name="Place">
 <option value="EG"></option>
 <option value="USA"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
 <option value="Test"></option>
</datalist>
 <input name="OK" type="submit"/>
```

Howeve if you need id then use both `id` and `name` attributes.